# Get a user id by the userName in mvc Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to get all the users list of a specific role and their IDs.

I have searched a lot to get a userId with the user name but i didn't get one. 
All of them are saying how to get the logged/current user id.

```
public ActionResult getAllAMUsers()
{
    var AMUserList = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Account Manager");
    var userList = new List<UserViewModel>(); // property userID & userName

    foreach(var item in AMUserList)
    {
       string userID = User.Identity.getUserID(item); // method like this
       userList.add(new UserViewModel{
           userName = item,
           userID = userID
       })
    }

    return View(userList);
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are using AD, you will need to query AD and pass in a filter of the values in AMUserList.

Comment: But sir isn't there any default method to get the user Id passing their name in mvc?

Comment: Show `AMUserList `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Account Manager").Select(Membership.GetUser).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks, got my answer.

Comment: Might be useful for others to post what you did in that case.

Comment: Actually i got my answer from your code above. Thank you again.